# How to get arrays on output from MongoDB aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents in MongoDB, like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a748c8b178227d602ec9ce8"),
    "dateHour" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:00:00.000Z"),
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"),
            "cap" : 437105726836.0
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"),
            "cap" : 437316498502.0
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Using aggregate method (in NodeJS):

```
db.getCollection('hourly').aggregate([
    {$match: {}}, 
    {$unwind: "$data"}, 
    {$project: {_id: 0, date: "$data.date", cap: "$data.cap" } }
])
```

I get output like:

```
[
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"),
        "cap" : 437105726836.0
    },
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"),
        "cap" : 437316498502.0
    }
]
```

**QUESTION: What is the most effective way to get output like so:**

```
[
    [ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"), 437105726836.0],
    [ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"), 437316498502.0]
]
```

**?**

I can simply add `.map(function(item) {return [item.date, item.cap]})` but is this most effective way when working with huge amount of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `$project` with `$map` or `$reduce`

$map

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
            _id : 0, 
            data : {$map : {input : "$data", as : "d", in : ["$$d.date", "$$d.cap"]}}
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

$reduce

```
db.col.aggregate(
    [
        {$project : {
            _id : 0, 
                data : {$reduce : {input : "$data", initialValue : [], in : {$concatArrays : ["$$value", [["$$this.date", "$$this.cap"]]]}}}
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

output

```
{
    "data" : [
        [
            ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"),
            437105726836
        ],
        [
            ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"),
            437316498502
        ]
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root has to be a document, proof:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$data"}, 
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: ["$data.date", "$data.cap"] } }
]);
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "'newRoot' expression must evaluate to an object, but resulting value was: [null, null]. Type of resulting value: 'array'. Input document: {date: 2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z, cap: 4.37106e+11}",
        "code" : 40228,
        "codeName" : "Location40228"
} : aggregate failed
```

You could, however, project it into an array within a document:

```
> db.test.aggregate([
...     {$unwind: "$data"},
... { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: {a:["$data.date", "$data.cap"] } }}
... ])
{ "a" : [ ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"), 437105726836 ] }
{ "a" : [ ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"), 437316498502 ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in the projection.  Try this:

```
db.getCollection('hourly').aggregate([
   {$match: {}}, 
   {$unwind: "$data"}, 
   {$project: {_id: 0, date: ["$data.date", "$data.cap"] } }
]);
```

Just in case my syntax is a little off, here is MongoDb documentation to [project a new array](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#example-project-new-array-fields).

I don't see why you need aggregate.

Why not:

```
db.getCollection('hourly').find({}, {data: 1}, (err, results) => {
   // manage results here.
});
```

Comment: On your first aggregate, result like so:
`[
    {date: [ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"), 437105726836.0]},
    {date: [ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"), 437316498502.0]}
]`

Comment: On second request result also not useful, like so:

`{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"),
            "cap" : 437105726836.0,
        }, 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:09:25.127Z"),
            "cap" : 437316498502.0,
        },
        ...
},
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2018-02-02T16:06:35.033Z"),
            "cap" : 437105726836.0,
        }, 
        ...`

Comment: On the first one, what's the problem?  It has your fields in an array of arrays, which looks like what you are seeking.   On the second one, it looks like you did not paste all of it.  So, why can't you use this format?  Maybe you can edit your question and explain.